# Logic regarding the use of spaces with Unary Operators in Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x

My problem started when I made an error when creating an index count for a for loop and I found a behavior in Python 3.4 that I did not understand.

```
> a = 1
> a =+ 2  #reversed 'plus and equal'
> a
2
> a += 2  #correct 'plus and equal'
> a
> a
4
```

At first I thought that this mistake should have returned an error, but I started thinking that the reversed 'plus and equal' logic may be instead interpreted as variable 'a' is equal to a positive integer '2'. To confirm this I tried setting a variable to a negative integer and then used it to change the sign of a variable.

```
> a =- 2
> a
-2
> a =- a
> a
2
> a = -a
> a
-2
```

This all left me wondering why a unary operator does not need to be adjacent to the integer or variable that is being changed.

Comment: I guess it's simply because it does not cause ambiguity (for the interpreter). The Python's source code before being interpreted is split into tokens that are then interpreted according to the semantics of the language.

Comment: That is fascinating.

Comment: It's parsed as `a = (+2)`. There is surely a duplicate with answer, unfortunately it's fairly hard to search for `=+` or `=-`. Ps. consider `a=-+-+2`,

Comment: Why should unary + or - raise an error?

Comment: @timgeb It's not just `+` or `-` that is expected to raise an error.  It's because right next to `=`, one might expect that python would not recognize it as a valid operator.  *It* being `=+`.

Comment: @zondo why would one expect this?

Comment: I tried searching for a while but as you said Rogalski , finding any information about '=+' or '=+' is a challenge. nbro : Your description of the mechanism was helpful I will read up on that. timgeb :  At first I thought it should return an error because it was not doing what I thought it should be doing, I then realized that it was interpreting it correctly in a way that I had not considered before creating a problem for myself.

Comment: @timgeb When you say `x + = 4`, there is an error.  Without the space, it is a recognized operation.  One *might* expect, therefore that `= +` without a space would be taken differently, but as `=+` is not a recognized operation, that might cause an error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Python reads right to left, in that what's on the right side of the equals gets interpreted first so you have the two sides:

```
(a) =(+ 2)
```

Whitespace is free space, so regardless of the whitespace the interpreter will still read lines of code as if the whitespace were not there. As such, Python interprets it as `equals +2` so, it's just like making an integer positive (or negative if you do `equals minus 2`)

```
>>> a =+ 2 # note the whitespace
>>> a
>>> 2
>>> a = +2 # consistent interpretation
>>> a 
2
>>> a =- 2 # no matter where
>>> a
-2
>>> a = -2 # the whitespace is
>>> a
-2
```

It's like how you don't have to have a space between around the equals when assigning. e.g:

```
a = 1
```

is the same as

```
a=1
```

The interpreter reads it in the appropriate order and manipulates the information as it interprets it.

Comment: This does not answer the question, IMO.

Comment: Thank you the code with parenthesis around each side makes the problem a lot clearer. The explanation you provided along with nbro's comment above regarding ambiguity helped me better understand why it works this way. I had always assumed that unary operators needed to be associated next to the integer or variable they operated upon.

Comment: @Nanook It was a good question. A lot of people in my into to InfoSec classes had the same question. You can write code without whitespace at all, but whitespace is free so you should use it for formatting. It helps with readability of your code, like if someone is reviewing your code for example.

Comment: This is very neat. Helped me out of the confusion, as to why. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If `a =+ 2` should throw an error, so should `a = +2`, since Python allows both `a = 2` and `a=2`; it doesn't really care about where you put your spaces (as long as you keep care of your indentation).

Interpreters and compilers are throwing errors when there is an error, and they have no idea what you really want. In this case, it's perfectly clear, as the behavior is well defined (you are just assigning a (redundantly declared) positive integer to a variable).

Interpreters and compilers shouldn't ask you "Is this really what you want?". Another example would be an assignment in an if condition, like `if (line = readLine())`. It's certainly possible that this happened by mistake, but it's still clear what's supposed to happen, and many developers are using this method to read from streams of data. (Although there is a language out there that's not allowing assignments in conditions, not sure which one it is...)

While interpreters and compilers shouldn't try to guess if that's actually a mistake done by the developer or not, tools for static code analysis are there to point out stuff like that, among other things.

So, to answer your question (*Is there any reason that reversed += should not return an error*): Yes. Because it's not an error.

### Update

As pointed out in the comments, it's actually Python that's not allowing assignments in conditions.

So I'm revising my answer: **No**, I don't think that there is any reason that this shouldn't be an error.
When Python is trying to avoid developer's mistakes (that's what they are saying [in the docs](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-conditions): *"[...]it avoids a common class of problems encountered in C programs: typing `=` in an expression when `==` was intended."*, it could do it in your case as well.

Comment: "Although there is a language out there that's not allowing assignments in conditions, not sure which one it is..." <- Python?