# =+ Python operator is syntactically correct

Tags: python, python-2.7, operators, language-lawyer, increment

I accidentally wrote:

```
total_acc =+ accuracy
```

instead of:

```
total_acc += accuracy
```

I searched the net and could not find [anything](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_basic_operators.htm). So what happened, why does Python think I mean what I am typing?

<sub>Computers trust us too much. :)</sub>

Comment: `total_acc =+ accuracy` is `total_acc = +accuracy`

Comment: Oh so when you want the negative value, you don't do *(-1), thanks @Clodion! Didn't know that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Logic regarding the use of spaces with Unary Operators in Python3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35208351/logic-regarding-the-use-of-spaces-with-unary-operators-in-python3)

Comment: There ain't any changes regarding this from 2 to 3. But (imo) this post has way better answers. Hence I am not marking this as dupe. (If there is a better dupe, then I have no probs)

Comment: Also @gsamaras `total_acc =  ​  ​  ​  ​ + ​  ​  ​  ​  ​   accuracy` would work ;)

Comment: Oh why the downvote? If it's something that should be improved, please let me know! Why @BhargavRao?

Comment: @BhargavRao I do not care about the rep, I just want to know if the question has something bad that the future reader should not read, that's why I am asking and I did not imply that you did. :) Can you explain why this will work?

Comment: Since you can put as many unary operators in a row as you want, you can really annoy your code reviewers with `total_sec+=-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-accuracy`.

Comment: That's almost as evil as it is the greek semicolon in my C++ code @tdelaney. :)

Comment: @gsamaras Python ignores all the spaces between operators and operands. Thus even your print statements can look like `print (  ​ ​ ​ ​ "something" ​ ​ ​ ​ ​)`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the same as if you were to do like `total_acc = -accuracy`, except positive instead of negative. It basically is the same as `total_acc = accuracy` though, as adding a + before a value does not change it.

This is called an *unary operator* as there is only one argument (ex: `+a`) instead of two (ex: `a+b`).

[This link](https://docs.python.org/2.0/ref/unary.html) explains it a little more.

Answer (score 9):

If you are interested in catching this type of errors early, you can do that with *static code analysis*. For example, [`flake8`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/flake8):

```
$ cat test.py
total_acc = 0
accuracy = 10

total_acc =+ accuracy
$ flake8 test.py
test.py:4:12: E225 missing whitespace around operator
```

In this case, it is complaining about the extra space after the `+`, thinking that you actually meant `total_acc = +accuracy`. This would have helped you to discover the problem earlier.

FYI, [`pylint`](http://www.pylint.org/) would catch that too.

Comment: Your answer adds *really* something special here, you deserve an upvote²!

Answer (score 2):

It thinks you're doing `total_acc = +accuracy`, which sets `total_acc` equal to `accuracy`. `+` before a variable without another value causes the variable's [`__pos__`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.__pos__) method to be called. For most types, this is a `nop`, but there are certain types, e.g. [`Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) that implement `__pos__`.

Comment: Yes that's correct, but what happens with `+` operator?

Comment: `+` before a value invokes the object's `__pos__()` method if it has one. Most types don't have such a method, so it's a no-op. `Decimal` is one type that does use it; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16819023/whats-the-purpose-of-the-pos-unary-operator-in-python

Comment: @kindall Huh, I did not know that. Good to know, thanks! I'll add that to my answer.